# How to extracts log of last one hour from logfile

Tags: unix, sftp

How to extracts log of last one hour from logfile?

This is log file

```
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text 
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 11:10:20 < ?xml version>
2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text 
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
sample text sample text
2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
sample text sample text
2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
```

Suppose time is 12:30, so output would be like
    2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
    2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
    sample text sample text
    sample text sample text
    sample text sample text
    sample text sample text
    sample text sample text
    sample text sample text 
    sample text sample text
    sample text sample text
    sample text sample text
    2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
    2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>
    sample text sample text
    2017-05-22 12:10:20 < ?xml version>

I had tried some options but its giving me all logs :-(

```
grep "^$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')" text.log

sed -e "1,/^$(date -d -1hour +'%Y-%m-%d %H')/d" text.log
```

While firing these queries its giving me all logs instead of one hour.
Please give me some suggestion?

Comment: How is this related to java ?

Comment: r u want some kind of unix command or java logic

Comment: i want to use unix command that i will fire from java

Comment: "$(date +"%F %R" --date=@$(expr `date +%s` - 3600))" -v end="$(date "+%F %R")" '$0 ~ start, $0 ~ end' I had tried this command too but this is giving exact previous 1 hour log only mean if i run at 10:15 then this is giving logs for 9:15 only

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot:

```
grep "$(date -v-60M +"%Y-%m-%d %H")" text.log
```

Comment: this is not wroking

Comment: Are you running over a recent log? I just ran the command on my /var/log/system.log file and it worked just fine.  You could try escaping the quotes in the date command:
`grep "$(date -v-60M +\"%Y-%m-%d %H\")" /var/log/wifi.log`